# Magento: Allow duplicate products in Collection

Tags: magento

I am developing a module to list part fitments and am running into a product collection problem with the following error:

Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "1150" already exist

What makes my question unique is that I **WANT** to have the product more than once in the collection, because I am listing all products that fit on a specific machine, and some products (bearings) will fit the machine in different places.

I am attaching fitment information to the collection so that each product will show where it goes on the machine and be sorted by fitment first, but it is important that the product be listed separately for each fitment in which it is included.

However, Magento does not like this and I haven't been able to come up with a solution. I traced the error to lib\Varien\Data\Collection.php

```
        if (isset($this->_items[$itemId])) {
            throw new Exception('Item ('.get_class($item).') with the same id "'.$item->getId().'" already exist');
        }
```

From this I see that the products are set into the array using the id as an array key, so I'm not sure if there is a good way to circumvent that to have a product multiple times in my collection.

EDIT:
 Here is my code to load the collection as asked.  It works fine for most selections so I don't have a problem with the code getting the right products, but rather that **some selections cause the same product to be listed more than once in the collection, which I want to happen, but Magento does not like**.

```
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $layer->setCurrentCategory(3);
    $collection = $layer->getProductCollection(); 

    $atvvalues = $session->getData($name);

    $atv_id = $db->select()
        ->from(array('fm'=>$collection->getTable('mcdfinder/vehicle')), 'id')
        ->where('fm.make = ? ', $atvvalues['make'])
        ->Where('fm.description = ?', $atvvalues['model'])
        ->Where('fm.year = ?', $atvvalues['year']);

    $collection->getSelect()->join(array('mmy' => $collection->getTable('mcdfinder/product')), 'mmy.product_id=e.sku', array('mmy.*'))
        ->where('mmy.vehicle_id = ?', $atv_id);

    $collection->getSelect()->join(array('atvcat' => $collection->getTable('mcdfinder/category')), 'atvcat.id=mmy.category_id', array('atvcat.*'));

    $collection->getSelect()->order( array('atvcat.category_gparent', 'atvcat.category_parent', 'atvcat.category_name', 'e.sku') );
```

So, I might have a product BG1 with an atvcat of 'Differential', but also a BG1 with an atvcat of 'Front Wheel', so I need it to appear twice in different places of the ordered collection

Comment: Can you post the code of how you are loading your collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this working by overriding lib\Varien\Data\Collection.php in my local folder.

I changed the first snippet in the question to this:

```
        if (isset($this->_items[$itemId])) {
            $this->_items[] = $item;
            //throw new Exception('Item ('.get_class($item).') with the same id "'.$item->getId().'" already exist');
        }
```

This line "$this->_items[] = $item;" borrows the logic from _addItem where an item with no id is added to the collection (since the problem before was a collision between duplicate items having the same id).

I'd love to hear why this is a bad solution (other than overriding Varien directly) or might cause problems, but so far things are working perfectly.

Comment: The bad part is that exceptions are thrown for a reason. Commenting out code at this level might cause other code to stop working as expected since these exceptions **should** be thrown and **should** be caught. I'm in a similar situation now. Commenting out the code is a good approach, however I would recommend rewriting the collection class for your case and only change it for that specific collection.